# Additivity of the Lebesgue Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I recently came across a problem in another proof I was reading.

We are in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Set $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
B^+ := B \cap \{x_n \geq 0\}  
\\ 
B^- := B \cap \{x_n \leq 0\} \end{matrix}\right.$$

The problem was to estimate the integral $\int_B$ where $B$ is an open ball $B :=B(x^0,r).$

Now the author estimated $\int_B$ by breaking it into the "disjoint" parts $\int_B =\int_{B^+} + \int_{B^-} + \int_{\{x_n = 0 \}}= \int_{B^+} + \int_{B^-} +0.$ The last integral is $0$ because it is integrating over a measure zero set.

I have never seen this technique used ever nor can I find this property in an analysis textbook, although it looks like it make sense. But if this is common property, someone tell me what book has this.

Is this property generally true? If you have a collection of sets $\{A_i\}$ and they are say pairwise $\mu(A_i \cap A_j) = 0$, we can estimate $\int_A = \sum \int_{A_i}$?

Comment: Just write $\int_B f $ as $\int 1_B f$. How does this help you?

Comment: @PhoemueX I think that only helps if we can write $B$ into disjoint sets, but that is not the case here.

Comment: But your sets are "almost disjoint" and this implies (check it!) that $1_{\bigcup A_i} = \sum 1_{A_i}$ **almost everywhere**.

Comment: Okay so I just checked on some finite cases and the equality you suggested is true a.e. But how does this still justify passing to the integral $\int \chi_{\{ \cup A_i \}} = \int \sum \chi_{A_i}$ a.e.?

Comment: If $f=g$ almost everywhere, then $\int f =\int g$.

Comment: Okay because $J^c = \{ f\neq g \}$ and $\int_A f = \int_J f + \int_{J^c} f = \int_J f = \int_J g$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint measurable  sets
and $f$ is any integrable function then $\int_{A \cup B} f=\int f_A+\int f_B$. This follows from additivity of the integral and the fact that $\chi_{A \cup B} f=\chi_A f+\chi_B f$.

Singleton sets in $\mathbb R$ form a disjoint family and it  is not true that $\int_{\mathbb R}f =\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} \int_{x}f$. However, additivity holds for countbale families $(A_n)$ with $\mu(A_i \cap A_j)=0$ for $i \neq j$. This is an easy consequence of Monotone Convergence Theorem.

[Note that if $E=\cup_{i\neq j} (A_i\cap A_j)$ then $\mu (E)=0$. Also $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \chi_{A_i\setminus E}$ increases to $\chi_A$ where $A =\cup_i A_i\setminus E$].

Comment: The OP seems to struggle already with the case of a finite family, so you might add that additivity of the integral also comes into play here.

Comment: Where is $\mu(A_i \cap A_j) =0$ being used in the Monotone convergence theorem result? Doesn't it just say in my case that $\lim \int_A f\sum_{i}^n \chi_{A_i} = \int_A f\chi_{A}$?

Comment: @Hawk I have edited my answer.

Comment: Am I missing something or your result only shows additivity on the sets $A_i \setminus E$ and not $A_i$ as intended? Since it shows $ \lim \int f\sum_{i=1}^{n} \chi_{A_i\setminus E} = \int f\chi_{A} = \int f\chi_{\cup_i A_i} + \int f \chi_E =\int f\chi_{\cup_i A_i} $

Comment: @Hawk $\int_A fd\mu=\int_{A\cap E} fd\mu+\int_{A \setminus E} fd\mu =\int_{A\cap E} fd\mu+0$ for any measurable set  $A$  and any integrable function $f$ because $\mu (E)=0$.

Comment: That doesn't actually show the result still right? You are still showing only additivity on $A_i \setminus E$ not on $A_i$

Comment: @Hawk $\int_A f=\int_{A\setminus E} f=\sum _i \int_{A_i\setminus E} f=\sum _i \int_{A_i} f$

Comment: Aren't you defining $A = \cup A_i \setminus E$ not as $A = \cup A_i$? So you showed $\int_ {\cup A_i \setminus E} = \sum_i \int_{A_i}$ Did you make a typo on the other comment because you wrote $\int_{A \setminus E} = 0$, but $A \setminus E = A$ since $A = \cup_i A_i \setminus E$ already do not have $E$.

Comment: @Hawk $A=\cup A_i$ and this implies  $A\setminus E=\cup A_i\setminus E$.